# Best practice for language key for "und" in hook_form_alter

Tags: 7, entities, hooks, i18n-l10n

I'm modifying in a form in my custom module. Code looks like:

```
function my_module_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {

    if ($form_id == "someID") {

        $form['field_charity_author']['und'][0]['value']['#value'] = arg(3);
        //$form['field_charity_author']['#type'] = 'hidden';

    }

}
```

However, I think hard-coding `und` is bad. What should be the proper way to modify form fields properly in this case?

Comment: This comment is probably irrelevant since it's asked a long time ago. 
One simple way I use it by using a `foreach` loop. If it's just LANGUAGE_NONE, that's a single run. In form_alter sense, it should technically alter whatever the language the form has.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Unfortunately, your self-answer is not so universal. Field language and node language are not the same things.
Field language is needed only if you are using Field Translation API (for example [Entity translation](http://drupal.org/project/entity_translation)). When you start using it, some fields are converted to translatable.

Translatable fields have language code, which really makes sense. But if the field is not translatable, the language code will always be (and for all content types, entities, etc) — `LANGUAGE_NONE` (best to use the constant `LANGUAGE_NONE` and not the string `'und'`).
So with your solution you can get a situation when a node is Russian, but a field of the node uses `LANGUAGE_NONE`.
Happily, fields are attached to the form with `'#language'` key, which always contains the correct language code.

```
$lang = $form['FIELDNAME']['#language'];
$form['FIELDNAME'][$lang][0]['value']['#value'] = $value;
```

If you have no access to attached form, [Field Language API functions](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.multilingual.inc/group/field_language/7) can be useful.

Comment: This is the only correct answer in this thread.

Comment: This method can also be used while retreiving the image field path of a node/content-type. Thanks

Answer (score 10):

If you know the entity type and bundle use something like the following code, which calls [field_language()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.multilingual.inc/function/field_language/7).

```
$field_language = field_language('node', $node, 'field_charity_author');  
$form['field_charity_author'][$field_language][0]['value']['#value'] = arg(3);
```

It will figure out the right language, and will work in multilingual sites.

Also have a look at [field_get_items()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.module/function/field_get_items/7).

Comment: This correct as API way.

Comment: What about if the node has not been created?

Comment: @Nikit I'm not sure, because display language and form language are not the same. Author alters some form and it can be form for creating new node or for adding new translation of existing node.

Comment: @kalabro - display language and form language - the same at current context.

Answer (score 4):

The whole `und` deal is one of the more annoying things in Drupal 7 that didn't work as well in practice as when it was designed.

Anyways you can get the first language using `array_keys` like this:

```
function my_module_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {

  if ($form_id == "someID") {
      $langs = array_keys($form['field_charity_author']);
      $form['field_charity_author'][$langs[0]][0]['value']['#value'] = arg(3);
  }
}
```

That should work all the time.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm pasting what I've done to fix this issue in another answer. :)

Comment: Can I use $langs  for accessing value of same field in the form_state too?

Comment: Is this really safe? Can you be sure $langs[0] is always the correct array item?

Answer (score 0):

*(Answering my own question in case it helps someone. The answer worked for me.)*

I can write following line to get the language:

```
$lang = $form['language']['#value'];    //  Instead of "und"
```

Comment: This is wrong. See [kalabro's answer](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/31639/199).

Answer (score 0):

re: kalabro's answer

his code didn't work for me - my code is a little different

```
$lang = $form['FIELDNAME']['#language'];
$form['FIELDNAME'][$lang]['#value'] = $value;
```

[$lang][0] returned "u" but the full value of [$lang] is "und"
and I did not need the ['value'] either,
because $form['FIELDNAME']['#language'] was not an array, it was a string.

Comment: The 0th character of 'und' is 'u'. You are in a maze of twisty little passages, all arrays.