# Custom Field Not Being Saved programattically through node_save()

Tags: entities, nodes

So there is a custom field I added called 'qid'.  I can see that it is being created with each node.  My issue is that I cannot programmatically save a value to my custom field.  In the code below I will display and instance where I add two values, one to my custom field `qid` and another to the Ubercart uc_product field `height`.  `Height` will be saved successfully and `qid` will not.

```
function my_module_test_page() {
  $output = t('foo');

  $node = node_load('151');
  dpm($node);
  $node->height = '555';
  $node->qid = '222';
  dpm($node);
  node_save($node);
  $test = node_load('151');
  dpm($test);

  return $output;

}
```

While I understand that this is probably not enough code to get to the root of the problem I have no idea where to look.  I have scoured the `node_save()` function and I dont understand why my field is having a problem.  If it helps I have checked `field_data_qid` in my MYSQL db; however, the table is empty.

EDIT: So the next interesting fold is that when I enter the QID field through the GUI it saves fine.

Comment: Is the `qid` field an integer or varchar in the database?  If it's an integer then it makes sense because you're passing a string in as the value.

Comment: Thats a good call Lester, thanks.  I checked and it is listed as a varchar(255).  Just to play around some more I tried submitting `$node->qid` as a string, an int, and an array with a string inside it - no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My suggestion would be to inspect an existing node that already has a value for field_data_qid. Is qid a field created through the Fields GUI? $node->qid is not where I'd expect to see a custom field like this.. $node->field_qid['und'][0]['value'] is a more likely candidate. You'd end up with:

```
function my_module_test_page() {
  $node = node_load(151);
  dpm($node, 'Pre-modified node');
  $node->field_qid['und'][0]['value'] = 222;
  dpm($node, 'Pre-saved modified node');
  node_save($node);
  // Passing TRUE for $reset to bump the cache
  $test = node_load(151, NULL, TRUE);
  dpm($test, 'Reloaded node');
  return 'Test page';
}
```

Also: node_load takes a nid integer as a parameter, not a string: http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.module/function/node_load/7

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7876458/drupal-6-drupal-7-migration-field-unds and [Best practice for language key for "und" in hook_form_alter](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/25839/best-practice-for-drupal-7-language-key-for-und-in-hook-form-alter)

Comment: I install the qid field in my .install file using `field_create_field` and `field_create_instance` as described in the docs for field creation.  I'm starting to think the problem could be back there.  Here's the code re: the field install. http://pastebin.com/MKGhuXqD

Comment: `$node->field_qid['und'][0]['value']`  was exactly the problem.  I also found the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5448889/programmatically-get-and-set-field-values  Can you explain why this language thing is such an issue?

Comment: i18n is a tough thing to master, but essentially the use of "und" - undefined language, leaves the option open of specifying per-language values for a given field, using the language code as the key. This gets important when your site needs to be multilingual, so Drupal fields, entities, and lots else are all built to be multilingual capable.

Comment: rhetorical: why doesn't it just default to the language type which I already specified in my $node value (which isn't listed in the sample code above but in my implementation I do use).  It seems like that would be a fair default situation and that `$node->field_qid['rus'][0]['value']` would be the exception not the rule, ie I had a Russian language field attached to an English language node.

Comment: It's that way to keep the structure of the arrays consistant, and to prevent people from being lazy. If these were object methods instead of arrays, it would be more doable, but that's not the design that was chosen. Drupal APIs... not quite as developer friendly as they could be.