# How to get a field value in form validate

Tags: 7, forms

i have a custom form validate function. what is the correct/reliable way to get the field value and why? below two lines get the same value from a Select List.

a) $form['field_a']['und']['#value']

b) $form_state['values']['field_a']['und'][0]['value']

Answer (score 2):

Refering to form API Drupal 7 for [#value](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#value)

```
$form['field_a']['und']['#value']
```

> Used by: button, hidden, image_button, submit, token, value
>
> Description: Used to set values that cannot be edited by the user.

For `$form_state['values']['field_a']['und'][0]['value']`

> **$form_state** is one of the arguments passed to a form submission
>   handler, or a form validation handler; its main usage is to retrieve
>   the values entered from the user in the form see the content of
>   $form_state['values'])

So you should use `$form_state['values']['field_a']['und'][0]['value']`

Comment: It would be recommended to use LANGUAGE_NONE constant instead of 'und'. Like this: $form_state['values']['field_a'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value']. If you have translatable fields check this out: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/25839/best-practice-for-drupal-7-language-key-for-und-in-hook-form-alter