# Prefill Registration Form Fields

Tags: 7, forms, commerce

- Entity Registration
- Commerce Registration
- Drupal 7

Our site connects with Salesforce to input Entity Registration data as Contacts. I'm building in the ability to have users login and have their registration forms prefilled with the data I grab from Salesforce.

I have the data, but the prefill isn't working. Commerce Registration buries the forms a bit, as you will see below in my code example. I decided to step out of using the Salesforce data and just use a static value and try to set it. Both default_value and placeholder do nothing. If I try to touch ['value'] the site crashes.

Here is the trimmed down version of what I have:

```
<?php
function createFieldMap(){
    $fieldMapping = array(
        "LastName" => "field_last_name",
        "FirstName" => "field_first_name",
        "Salutation" => "field_prefix"
    );
}
function custom_module_form_commerce_checkout_form_registration_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    $fieldMap = createFieldMap();
    foreach ($form['registration_information']['register_entities'] as $name => $data) {
        foreach($form['registration_information'][$name] as $subname => $subdata) {
            foreach ($fieldMap as $salesforceKey => $drupalMachine) {
                if($drupalMachine == 'field_last_name'){
                   $form['registration_information'][$name][$subname]['field_last_name']['#default_value'] = "Johnston";
                   $form['registration_information'][$name][$subname]['field_last_name']['#attributes']['placeholder'] = t("Johnston");
               }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Just to point out, **$form['registration_information'][$name][$subname]** is valid and is done that way because if you have multiple forms, the productID is used as the form ID, twice. I can access **$form['registration_information'][$name][$subname]['field_last_name']** if I var_dump it out. **['value']** represents entity data for some reason, which is probably why it crashes if I try to adjust that.

I can get this to work fine by setting the default_value of select lists. But the text fields don't do anything.

Comment: I have no idea of commerce / Salesforce, and form alters aren't easy for me,  but in general, I thought text fields should have a language.. Usually it's like Language_None or something. See https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/25839/best-practice-for-language-key-for-und-in-hook-form-alter Edit: Just saw you fixed it. The `und` is the language part of it

Comment: Thanks Niall. I did try before using und/LANGUAGE_NONE but still couldn't get it to work, but noticed it was deeper down the array tree that I needed to go. oh nesting..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it. I had to work with
['und'][0]['value']['#default_value']

So my new code is:

```
<?php
    $fieldMap = createFieldMap();
    foreach ($form['registration_information']['register_entities'] as $name => $data) {
        foreach($form['registration_information'][$name] as $subname => $subdata) {
            foreach ($fieldMap as $salesforceKey => $drupalMachine) {
                $form['registration_information'][$name][$subname][$drupalMachine]['und'][0]['value']['#default_value'] = $contact[$salesforceKey];                                 
            }
        }
    }
```